# Why does R impute the 12th of the month when formatting a year as a Date

Tags: r, date

I note in R if one calls `as.Date(as.character(2002:2013), format='%Y')` the output is

```
[1] "2002-01-12" "2003-01-12" "2004-01-12" ...
```

I would like R to give me the first of the month instead. I could supply the whole date, `paste(2002, '01', '01', sep='-')`, but am curious why the year-only format imputes the 12th of the month and also to see other solutions.

Comment: You could also use `ISOdate(2002:2013,1,1)`

Answer (score 1):

Ah, just found my answer: The missing sections of the Date object (month/day) are imputed from today's date (System Date).